# How to handle too many ViewModels in non-MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, model

I have big `asp.net web-forms` project, I'm using `Linq2SQL`, I have 1 model per table (same properties as generated classes by Linq2SQL, I add this models to have more controls of fields).

For some tables I need multiple ViewModels, for example for Product table I have following models:

- `ProductBaseViewModel` *contains `Id`, `Title`, `Price`*
- `ProductPageViewModel` *derived from `ProductBaseViewModel` and have `Description` and `Review` properties*
- `ProductBoxViewModel` *contains `Id`, `StockCount`, `Title`, `Url` and `FormattedPrice`*
- `ProductWebApiViewModel` *I use this one in `API` layer*
- I have 3 more ViewModels that related to `Product`!

I think having this kind of models are silly and I'm looking for some better solution, is there better way (*I'm sure the answer is yes*) for handling `ViewModel`s in large projects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of all this abstraction?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I use this models to my WebAPI layer, in my html templates, as mapped model in my LINQ queries.

Comment: OK.  What is the purpose of that?

Comment: The main reason is strongly typed models. also I use multiple models, because of performance (specially when I use that model as mapped model in my queries). for ex. I don't need to select `Description` field every time I select a product _it's NVARCHAR(MAX)_ so I need one model without that. I hope I could mention the point.